# Force www. even with subdomain not working without /

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site example.com and also a subdomain and I want the following redirect:

subdomain.example.com -> www.subdomain.example.com

example.com -> www.example.com

I use the following code

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force www. always and SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]

# Force SSL if already www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
```

Now the problem is that *subdomain.example.com* doesn't redirect but *subdomain.example.com/* **does**.

I also get a Server Error when going to example.com, although it does redirect to www. correctly.

The point with these redirects is so that I can in the same .htaccess file in the root folder hopefully redirect the subdomains to subdomain.com more easily, I have several domains on one server.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine the directives together like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

=> Check if HTTPS is off, or if the domain name does not begin with www, and then redirect to https://www.whatever.